# Is there a way to time parts of a query in mariadb built into the engine?

Tags: mariadb, benchmarking

In a mysql or mariadb query, the client sends the request, which is then interpreted, a plan is developed if the call is not a stored procedure, the data is manipulated and then data may be sent back to the client from 1 or more requests.

Is there a way to time at least some of these built into Maradb? If there isn't I could build from source, find the code, and record the times on the server side for each piece, but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: See if `ANALYZE SELECT ...` suffices.

Comment: what question are you trying to answer by timing each piece?

Comment: Maybe a slow query log [with explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/) is [sufficient](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/). [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) also breaks it down, as does [profiles](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-profile/).

Comment: @ysth I want to know how much time queries are taking in each piece, what percentage of the time parsing, translating the output to ASCII is taking as opposed to getting the data from the tables.

I found:

SET profile=1
it doesn't do everything I want, but it does do a lot.

Comment: I understand that is what you are asking for.  I am asking why you ask, what you are going to do with this information.

Comment: There is an excellent presentation from Valerii Kravchuk which might give you more tips on analyzing and profiling MariaDB Server: [Dynamic Tracing of MariaDB Server on Linux](https://mariadb.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/dynamictracing_serverfest2020.pdf)